# Input loses focus after the first character is entered, even with a key specified

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering an array of strings as text inputs. When rendering, I render one extra input, which updates an index one past the end of the array. The problem is that after the first character has been entered, when the new input is first rendered, the current input loses focus. ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vmevvb2h/1/))

The items have a key prop, including the one extra item past the end of the array. Should I file a bug report, or is there something I am missing here about how form inputs work?

```js
let MiniList = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            items: []
        };
    },

    update( index, value ) {
        let items = this.state.items;
        items[ index ] = value;
        this.setState({ items: items });
    },

    renderItem( value, index ) {
        return (
            <div key={ index }>
                { index }
                <input type="text"
                    value={ value }
                    onChange={ event => this.update( index, event.target.value )}/>
            </div>
        );
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.state.items.map( this.renderItem )}
                { this.renderItem( null, this.state.items.length )}
            </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render( <MiniList />, document.body );
```

Comment: as soon as you type a character, the state is being set and the component is re-rendered. Because of that the input is not focused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div>
    { this.state.items.map( this.renderItem )}
    { this.renderItem( null, this.state.items.length )}
</div>
```

compiles to

```
React.createElement("div", null,
    this.state.items.map( this.renderItem ),
    this.renderItem( null, this.state.items.length )
)
```

Where the key of every element in `this.state.items.map( this.renderItem )` will be prefixed by the index of the array in the children list (in your case, `0`). This makes reconciliation between any element in `this.state.items.map( this.renderItem )` and the element returned by `this.renderItem( null, this.state.items.length )` impossible, as they will not share the same key. So when you add a new item to `this.state.items`, the last input is unmounted and a new input is mounted in its place, which explains the loss of focus.

To fix this, make sure that all your item elements are in the same array.

```
<div>
    {
        this.state.items
            .map( this.renderItem )
            .concat( [this.renderItem( null, this.state.items.length )] )
    }
</div>
```

or simply

```
<div>
    { this.state.items.concat([null]).map( this.renderItem ) }
</div>
```